# Vaadin Designer Set Tab Caption

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

Problem according to the Vaadin docs to set a Tab caption do the following.

```
// Set an attribute using the returned reference
tabsheet.addTab(myTab).setCaption("My Tab");
```

When using the Vaadin designer you already have a Tab created within the design.

How do you set the name of the Tab?

Comment: You can set TabCaption in Designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You resolve this by first getting the Tab from the Design and then setting the caption for the Tab.  `addTab()` will add another Tab.

```
// Set an attribute using the returned reference
tabsheet.getTab(myTab).setCaption("My Tab");
```